# Несколько значений в info.plist

Tags: macos

Имеется info.plist, где key - value, class - string, value - box. Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то прописать несколько box (box1, box2 и далее)? Если да, то как?
Пробовал по-разному, через запятую, точку с запятой и прочее, не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно прописать их через любой удобный вам разделитель, но при чтении вы всё равно получите один экземпляр NSString, который придётся парсить на отдельные элементы вручную.

Проще будет поменять class поля на array, и перечислить элементы в качестве массива.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, только сейчас прочитал. Можно немножко подробнее на счёт "в качестве массива"? А данный момент сделал несколько box (box1, box2 и далее), что не совсем правильно (наверное) и удобно.